# SSH key mixup on GitHub

Tags: github, ssh, key

I'm having trouble committing to GitHub under my own account because of a mix-up with SSH keys. I'm not entirely sure how SSH keys work, so please forgive me if I make any incorrect statements.

A friend of mine used my computer to commit to her own GitHub account, and had to create a new key to do so. Now every time I commit, it shows up as committing from her account.

So far, she has deleted that key from her account, and I've tried making a new key to commit from. But my commits still show up under her name. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now every time I commit, it shows up as committing from her account.

Check if "shows up as committing from her account" means that you see her name associated with the commits.

Because if that is the case, it has nothing to do with SSH key.

Regarding SSH, you can check the output of:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

If you see your name, you are *pushing* as you.

But the commits might still be with here login. For that, check the output of:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

If a simple git log shows you that, locally, commits were done with the wrong name/author, you might need to change those commits and restore the proper name author (you): see "[GitHub help page: Changing author info](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info)".

Comment: thank you so much! Update: running `git config user.email` displayed her email and I overwrote it with `git config --global user.email myemail`